# NullReferenceException in MassTransit.dll after UseConsumeFilter

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to register my scoped consume filter:

```
serviceCollectionConfigurator.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
{
    //some code...

    cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(MyFilter<>), context);
});
```

But then in runtime I get NullReferenceException in MassTransit.dll when a message should be consumed. It doesn't even visit filter's constructor. Everything works fine when I remove this filter registration or when I change the filter and register it as non scoped filter. What can be the reason of my issue?

The filter code:

```
public class MyFilter<T> : IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>> where T : class
    {
        public MyFilter()
        {
        }

        public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
        {
            context.CreateFilterScope("ExternalMessageFilter");
        }


        public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
        {
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What version of MassTransit? Did you add your filter to the container?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson

I didn't add the filter to the container manually, just did cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(MyFilter<>), context) as it was shown in the MassTransit documentation. Should I register it as services.AddScoped<IMyFilter, MyFilter>()?

Masstransit version is 7.0.0.

A little more info: exception fails in the ConsumePipe.cs in the Task IPipe<ConsumeContext>.Send(ConsumeContext context) method.

StackTrace: "  at MassTransit.Scoping.Filters.ScopedFilter`1.<Send>d__2.MoveNext()"

Comment: Yes, you need to configure the container for the filter, otherwise the container doesn't know how to resolve it. AddScoped(typeof(MyFilter<>)) would do it.

Comment: Oh, thanks, it works. Just one more question... I successfully inject ConsumeContext into my Consumer dependecy. But when I try to inject the same dependency into the filter I get MassTransit.ConsumeContextNotAvailableException on all consume context properties. How can it be resolved? I need to inject a service which uses consume context.
Thank you!

Comment: It should work, make sure your dependency is scoped as well.